# CSS lost after clicking on menu using JSF with PrimeFaces

Tags: java, css, jsf, layout, primefaces

When I click on a `p:menuitem` and update the contents of a layoutunit, I lose the layoutunit CSS style. However, if I refresh, the style reappears. Why is this?

```html
<p:layout id="plantillaPrincipal" fullPage="true" >
            <p:layoutUnit id="cabe" position="north">


                <h:form id="bmenu">

                    <p:menubar>

                        <p:menuitem id="inicio" value="INICIO" actionListener="#{controlMenu.mostrarOpcion()}" update=":container">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="inicio" target="#{controlMenu.opcion}"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="tarifas" value="TARIFAS" actionListener="#{controlMenu.mostrarOpcion()}" update=":container">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="tarifas" target="#{controlMenu.opcion}"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="tasas" value="TASAS" actionListener="#{controlMenu.mostrarOpcion()}" update=":container">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="tasas" target="#{controlMenu.opcion}"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="dudas" value="DUDAS" actionListener="#{controlMenu.mostrarOpcion()}" update=":container">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="dudas" target="#{controlMenu.opcion}"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="consultas" value="CONSULTAS" actionListener="#{controlMenu.mostrarOpcion()}" update=":container">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="consultas" target="#{controlMenu.opcion}"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                    </p:menubar>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit> 

            <p:layoutUnit id="container" position="center">
                <h:form id="fcont">
                    <ui:insert name="panelInicio">...</ui:insert>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
```

---

This is the content of layoutunit to update

```html
<ui:define name="panelInicio">
    <h:form id="inicio" rendered="#{controlMenu.opcion=='inicio'}">  
        <p:panel id="pinicio">hola desde inicio</p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="tarifas" rendered="#{controlMenu.opcion=='tarifas'}">           
        <p:panel id="ptarifas">hola desde tarifas</p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="tasas" rendered="#{controlMenu.opcion=='tasas'}">            
        <p:panel id="ptasas">hola desde tasas</p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="dudas" rendered="#{controlMenu.opcion=='dudas'}">
        <p:panel id="pdudas">hola desde dudas</p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="consultas" rendered="#{controlMenu.opcion=='consultas'}">
        <p:panel id="pconsultas">hola desde consultas</p:panel>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

---

This is the managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class controlMenu {
public String opcion="";

public String getOpcion() {
    return opcion;
}

public void setOpcion(String opcion) {
    this.opcion = opcion;
}

public controlMenu(){       

}

public void mostrarOpcion(){
    System.out.print(opcion);

}
```

Comment: In firefox is there a different behaviour for f5 and ctrl+f5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update `LayoutUnit`s, they don't have a renderer. Add a placeholder like `OutputPanel` inside the unit and update it instead.